# Options for using BigQuery TABLESAMPLE results to filter two tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have one big table which I want to sub-sample once and use that result to filter two other tables. To do so, I have constructed a query which is something like this:

```sql
with subset_ids as (
  select 
    distinct(id) as id 
  from `project.dataset.very_large_table` 
  TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (25 percent)
),
sampled_table_1 as (
  select * from `project.dataset.table_1` t1
  right join subset_ids
  on t1.id = subset_ids.id
),
sampled_table_2 as (
  select * from `project.dataset.table_2` t2
  right join subset_ids
  on t2.id = subset_ids.id
),
select * from sampled_table_1
UNION ALL
select * from sampled_table_2
```

In this query I'm getting a subset of IDs using the TAMPLESAMPLE clause and then joining two tables on that subset to filter those tables and ultimately doing anything with them - in this case just UNION-ing them together but that's not the important bit.

This gives me the following error:

> sampling of table project.dataset.very_large_table not supported. Possible reasons: (1) sampled table referenced more than once or (2) sampling used inside IN subquery.

Which makes sense - the random sampling is not deterministic and will give different results each time.

Short from writing the subsampled list of IDs to a temp table, **what other options are there to re-use a sampled table**?

Comment: create temp table ooff of tablesample and then use it. sound obvious, have you tried?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant like I said in the last sentence - _apart_ from writing to a temp table, are there other options? Guess it may be a dead-end question with that being the only feasible option but was curious.

Comment: i missed that part :o) anyway - looks to me like this is the only option